# SSIS job success but package didn't run

Tags: ssis

I created a SSIS package that imports a file then moves the file to a folder called Archive.
I created a job that runs the package. The pack works fine when I run it from the MSDB folder. When I run the job I get the following success message:

> Started: 5:05:35 PM DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_SUCCESS (0). Started: 5:05:35 PM Finished: 5:05:37 PM Elapsed:
>   1.625 seconds. The package executed successfully. The step succeeded.

showing that the job supposedly completed successfully.

I know that the package the not run because the data did not get imported and the file did not move.

Can anyone explain the package may not run but we still get a job completion status of success?

Comment: Are you doing any logging for this package?

Comment: Also is your environment set up properly? How are you setting your file mappings?

Comment: Did you try running it locally? I mean not calling from a job..